# error:force close android program

Tags: android, eclipse

hi Apps for Android 5 error force close  but no problem for Android 4 please help me

LogCat error :

```
 09-13 13:23:50.441: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1627): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    09-13 13:24:02.697: I/Choreographer(1627): Skipped 189 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-13 13:24:05.527: W/Resources(1627): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x1 a=-1}
    09-13 13:24:05.531: W/Resources(1627): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x5 a=-1}
    09-13 13:24:05.591: W/Resources(1627): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x2 a=-1}
    09-13 13:24:06.952: I/Choreographer(1627): Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-13 13:24:08.230: I/Choreographer(1627): Skipped 123 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-13 13:24:10.963: E/Autocall(1627): -----Recording stoped
    09-13 13:24:10.963: E/MediaRecorder(1627): stop called in an invalid state: 0
    09-13 13:24:10.994: D/AndroidRuntime(1627): Shutting down VM
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): Process: com.example.c, PID: 1627
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.c.AutoAnswerReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2619)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at com.example.c.AutoAnswerReceiver.onReceive(AutoAnswerReceiver.java:223)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2612)
    09-13 13:24:11.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     ... 9 more
```

AutoAnswerReceiver Activity

```
  public class AutoAnswerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static MediaRecorder recorder; 
  public static boolean recordStarted=false;
  private Context ctx; 

  String phoneNumber;
  byte[] incrept; 
  byte[] decrpt;
  String selected_song_name;
  private static String recordPath; 
  public static boolean wasRinging = false;
  Boolean isOffHook = false;
  private static String inCall;
  DatabaseHandler db;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  Context context;
  AudioManager am;
  Cursor c;
  boolean callAgain;
  String key_which_call;
  String key_sms_template;
  String contactId=null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    db=new DatabaseHandler(context);
    this.context=context;
    key_which_call=prefs.getString("list_answer_calls", "1");
    am= (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    key_sms_template=prefs.getString("key_sms_template", "I am in meeting.Please call later.");
    if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        inCall = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        c=db.getPhoneCall(inCall);
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            String lastCallAt=c.getString(2);
            long millis=Long.parseLong(lastCallAt);
            long curr_mills=cal.getTimeInMillis();
            long diff=curr_mills-millis;
            int hours=(int) (diff/(1000*60*60));
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Last call :"+new Date(millis)+" hours:"+hours+"diff:"+diff, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("AutocallAnswer", "Last call :"+new Date(millis)+" hours:"+hours+"diff:"+diff);
            if(hours>=1)
            {
                callAgain=true;
                db.updatePhoneCall(String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()), inCall);
            }
            else
            {
                callAgain=false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String millis=String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            db.addCallCount(inCall,millis);
            callAgain=true;
        }

        if(callAgain)
        {
            if(prefs.getBoolean("key_callsms", false))
            {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "In SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //sendMessage(inCall);
                setRingerSilent();
                try {
                    Log.e("CallService", "-------> Delay :"+prefs.getString("list_delay_calls", "2")+"hello");
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("list_delay_calls", "2")) * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // We don't really care
                }
                try {
                    endInCall();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sendMessage(inCall);


            }
            else if(prefs.getBoolean("key_callrecord", false))
            {

                if(key_which_call.equals("1"))
                {
                //  setRingerSilent();
                    wasRinging=true;
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoAnswerIntentService.class));

                }
                else if(key_which_call.equals("2") || key_which_call.equals("3"))
                {
                    if(contactExists(context, inCall))
                    {
                    //  setRingerSilent();
                        wasRinging=true;
                        context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoAnswerIntentService.class));

                    }
                }
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming call"+inCall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(prefs.getBoolean("key_callsms", false) || prefs.getBoolean("key_callrecord", false))
            {
                if(prefs.getBoolean("key_callsms", false))
                {
                    setRingerSilent();
                }
                if(key_which_call.equals("1"))
                {
                    //setRingerSilent();
                    wasRinging=true;
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoAnswerIntentService.class));

                }
                else if(key_which_call.equals("2") || key_which_call.equals("3"))
                {
                    if(contactExists(context, inCall))
                    {
                        //setRingerSilent();
                        wasRinging=true;
                        context.startService(new Intent(context, AutoAnswerIntentService.class));

                    }
                }
            }

        }   

    }
    else if(phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Call answered:"+inCall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(wasRinging==true)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "call recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //startRecording();
            startRecording();
        }

    }
    else if(phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
    {
        wasRinging=false;

        setRingerNormal();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Call Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(recordStarted)
        {

            Log.e("Autocall", "-----Recording stoped");
            if(recorder!=null)
            {   
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }

                String name=getContactName(context, inCall);
                Uri photoUri=getPhotoUri();
                String photo=null;
                if(name==null)
                {
                    name="Unkonown";
                    photo="NA";
                }
                if(photoUri==null)
                {
                    photo="NA";
                }
                else
                    photo=photoUri.toString();
                CallRecord callRecord=new CallRecord();
                callRecord.setName(name);
                callRecord.setNumber(inCall);
                callRecord.setPhotoUri(photo);
                callRecord.setCallTime(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                callRecord.setRecordPath(recordPath);
                db.addCallHistory(callRecord);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Call recorded saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createNotification();

            recordStarted = false;

        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void endInCall() throws Exception
{
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);
     Object telephonyInterface = m.invoke(tm);

     // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
     Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
     Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

     // Invoke endCall()
     methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);
}
private void sendMessage(String number)
{
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, key_sms_template, null, null);
        // Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(context,
         "SMS faild, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
private void setRingerSilent()
{
    //For Normal mode


    //For Silent mode
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

    //For Vibrate mode
    //am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}
private void setRingerNormal()
{
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
private int getNotifCount()
{
    return prefs.getInt("notifCount", 1);
}

public void createNotification() {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected

    // call widget update
    Intent intentW = new Intent(context, AutoCallAnswerWidget.class);
    intentW.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AutoCallAnswerWidget.class));
    intentW.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
    context.sendBroadcast(intentW);
    //////////////////////////
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("New voice message");
    mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit:New message received");
    int notifNumber=getNotifCount();
    notifNumber++;
    mBuilder.setNumber(notifNumber);
    mBuilder.setContentText("You have "+notifNumber+" new voice message");
    //mBuilder.setSubText("You have "+notifNumber+" new voice message");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wicon);
    int notifId=1;
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,InboxActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(InboxActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //mBuilder.setNumber(1);


    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    nm.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());
    Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("notifCount", notifNumber);
    editor.commit();
  }
public void startRecording()
{
    try 
    {
        Log.e("AutoAnswerReceiver", "Hello ----> auto answer called");
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        File file = createDirIfNotExists("AUD"+getTimeStamp());
        recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        recordPath=file.getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        recordStarted = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
 public static String getTimeStamp() {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String sTime = now.format("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S");
        return sTime;
    }
public File createDirIfNotExists(String path) 
{
    selected_song_name = path;
    String dirpath=prefs.getString("key_voicemail_path", null);
    if(dirpath==null)
        dirpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/CallRecorder";
    File folder = new File(dirpath);
    if (!folder.exists()) 
    {
        if (!folder.mkdirs()) 
        {
           Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "folder is created");
        }
    }
    String list_file_type=prefs.getString("list_file_type", "2");
    String fileExt=null;
    if(list_file_type.equals("2"))
        fileExt=".mp3";
    else
        fileExt=".amr";
    File file = new File(folder, path + fileExt);
    try 
    {
        if (!file.exists()) 
        {
            if (file.createNewFile()) 
            {
                 Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "file is created");
            }

        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("AutoAnswerReceiver", "Error:"+e.toString());
    }
    return file;
}


public  String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) 
{
    /// number is the phone number
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
    Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try 
    {
       if (cur.moveToFirst()) 
       {
          return true;
       }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (cur != null)
           cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}

 public Uri getPhotoUri() {
     long contID=0;
     try {
         ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
         contID=Long.parseLong(contactId);
         Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                 .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                         null,
                         ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                 + "="
                                 + contactId
                                 + " AND "

                                 + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                 + "='"
                                 + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                 + "'", null, null);

         if (cursor != null) {
             if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 return null; // no photo
             }
         } else {
             return null; // error in cursor process
         }

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     }

     Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
             ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contID);
     return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
             ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media recorder is not in a recording state when `stop()` is being called.  The following is a possible cause if this is specific to Android 5.

In your code, you are using a broadcast receiver to handle incoming broadcast messages whenever there is a change to the phone state. There are basically 3 states which you could retrieve from `intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)` : `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` and `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`.  The `onReceiver()` is called upon change of state.

The sequence of state changes is usually:
`EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` (incoming ring) -> `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` (talking) -> `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` (Hang up).

Your code relies on the state change to initiate / stop recording.

It is observed that in Android 5, the system may send duplicate PhoneStateChange events (e.g. `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` -> `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` ->`EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` -> `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` -> `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` -> `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`).

In the above sequence, your code would stop the recorder in the first `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` by calling `recorder.stop()`. Upon receiving the second `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, your code may call `recorder.stop()` again, resulting in an illegal state.

Your code already uses the `recordStarted` variable to check if recording has started, before stopping the recorder.  However, the `recordStarted` variable is only reset at the end of processing `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, during which a second `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` may be broadcast.

To better guard again the possibility of duplicated calls to `recorder.stop()`, a quick fix is to set `recordStarted` to false as soon as possible, to minimise the chance that the duplicate `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` would trigger a second `recorder.stop()`

```
else if(phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
    {
        wasRinging=false;

        setRingerNormal();

        if(recordStarted)
        {
            recordStarted = false;

            Log.e("Autocall", "-----Recording stoped");

            :
            createNotification();

         }
```

You may also wish to declare the variable `recordStarted` as volatile -

```
public static volatile boolean recordStarted=false;
```

Comment: I have modified the code according to your orders, but the audio files stored twice Please help

Comment: Try setting wasRinging=false after you start recording.

Comment: I change the code with you but please do not resolve the issue further guidance